# Session variables not working on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, session-variables

I'v search a lot but cannot find anything helpful and I'm running out of ideas to solve this problem.

I'm trying to figure out **why session-variables are not working** on Heroku. 
Its a RoR application.

**Problem**
What ever is stored in session[:something] is not
kept till the next request.

To simplify my question I made a method that's saves a session-varable and
counts it up by one on each page refresh. it looks like this

```
def test
    if !session[:x]
        session[:x] = 0
    end
    session[:x] += 1
    render plain: session[:x]
end
```

When I then go to http://localhost:3000/api/test the number is displayed
and counts up every time I refresh the page.

When I deploy to Heroku and go to something-app.herokuapp.com/api/test

The number will always be one.

Clearly the session variable is not stored between the sessions.

I've tried running

```
$heroku features:enable http-session-affinity
```

but it didn't make it work.

**So what things could possible prevent the session to work on Heroku?**

I have also asked Heroku but they replayed with "an issue that falls outside the nature of the Heroku support policy"

I'm happy for all possible ideas.

Rails 5.0.2
Ruby 2.4.0p0

Comment: Maybe part 3 of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11998563)?

Comment: You can try cookies instead ;)

Comment: Good idea Mohamed. I will try that.